# SharePoint admin Latest certifications

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, 2016, certification

I am working as a SharePoint admin and have 6 years of exp.I would like to go for certification.

Please suggest 70-339  certification belongs to SharePoint admin?

Answer (score 7):

**First,** `70-339 Managing Microsoft SharePoint Server 2016` is not a certificate, it's a part (exam) of MCSE: SharePoint Solutions Expert certificate.

**Second,** `70-339 Managing Microsoft SharePoint Server 2016` exam is broken into 7 main area

1. Design SharePoint infrastructure (15–20%)
2. Plan authentication and security (15–20%)
3. Plan workload optimization (15–20%)
4. Plan productivity solutions (15–20%)
5. Manage search capabilities (10–15%)
6. Plan and configure cloud services (5–10%)
7. Monitor and optimize a SharePoint environment (10–15%)

All the above areas concentrate on SharePoint Administrator and Architect role

Check the detail of each area at [Managing Microsoft SharePoint Server 2016](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/learning/exam-70-339.aspx)

**Third,** `MCSE: SharePoint Solutions` is for IT Pros who are responsible for the configuration, administration, deployment, and management of the SharePoint Server 2016, so it's so suitable for you as **SharePoint Administrator**

**Finally,** To be `MCSE: SharePoint Solutions` Expert certified you will walk through 3 steps:

1. Managing Office 365 Identities and Requirements.
2. Enabling Office 365 Services.

   - After successfully completing steps 1 and 2, you'll earn a Microsoft Certified Solutions Associate (MCSA): Office 365 certification.
3. Managing Microsoft SharePoint Server 2016.

The preparation options for MCSE SharePoint 2016 are the below official courses

- [20339-1: Planning and Administering SharePoint 2016](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/learning/course.aspx?cid=20339-1)
- [20339-2: Advanced Technologies of SharePoint 2016](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/learning/course.aspx?cid=20339-2)

Read more at [MCSE: SharePoint Solutions Expert](https://www.microsoft.com/en-sa/learning/mcse-sharepoint-certification.aspx)