# Microsoft Certification for SharePoint Online Development

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365-developer

I have overall experience in SharePoint Online Development mainly client side which includes hands-on experience in Branding, CSOM, JSOM, Rest API, SharePoint Add-ins, Console Application, JavaScript, and Jquery.

I want to do Microsoft Certification in SharePoint so which certification will be good for me as per my experiences.

Answer (score 4):

As per your current development experience, you are searching for something like

**`MCSD: SharePoint Applications Solutions Developer`**

**Unfortunately,** This certification retired on March 31, 2017,  and the replacement certification is

**`MCSD: App Builder`**.

**For more details check**

- [MCSD: SharePoint Applications Solutions Developer](https://www.microsoft.com/en-sa/learning/mcsd-sharepoint-apps-certification.aspx)
- [MCSD: App Builder Microsoft Certified Solutions Developer](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/learning/mcsd-app-builder-certification.aspx)

Also, you might be interested to check [SharePoint admin Latest certifications](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/229610/sharepoint-admin-latest-certifications/229620#229620)

Comment: Is this answer still valid in August 2019? I heard there is lots of change in certifications. Could you please update same?